# Are there Metacity themes for Unity?

Tags: unity, themes, metacity

Any resources/collections/repositories for Unity themes?
Is there any chance is Metacity themes will be supported, at least in terms of window controls and window borders?

Answer (score 3):

Check out this article on OMGUbuntu. This solution may be useful for the moment.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/unity-panel-button-replacements-for-elementary-and-orta/

Answer (score 0):

The Unity menubar can be themed through GTK+3 and CSS by creating sections for `UnityPanelWidget` and `.unity-panel`.

The window controls as seen in the Unity menubar can easily be themed. The folder for a theme which alters them will have a `unity` folder inside it at the top, and inside it will need image files with the following names:

- `close.png`
- `close_focused_prelight.png`
- `close_focused_pressed.png`
- `minimize.png`
- `minimize_focused_prelight.png`
- `minimize_focused_pressed.png`
- `unmaximize.png`
- `unmaximize_focused_prelight.png`
- `unmaximize_focused_pressed.png`